# How to return tree within same level efficiently

Tags: algorithm

I have a tree with nodes that implement this interface
Interface Node {
    public boolean hasChildren() {};

}

How can I return a List of List with same treeLevel ?
for example if I have a tree like
                           1
          2                             3
   4        5                  6        7

I'll return a list of list like this {{1}{2,3}{4,5,6,7}}
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag this "genetic-algorithm"?

Comment: It is impossible to do what you want if the only operation you can perform on a node is to find out *whether* it has children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a [breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_Traversal), except at each level you keep a list of that level. something like this example C# code:

```
 IEnumerable<Node[]> Traverse(Node root) {
      Node[] currentLevel = new [] { root };
      Node[] nextLevel = null;
      while(true) { 
          nextLevel = currentLevel.SelectMany(n => n.Children).ToArray();
          if (nextLevel.Length > 0) {
             yield return nextLevel;
             currentLevel = nextLevel;
          } 
          else { 
              break;
          }
      }
 }
```